# How to import gpg secret/private key from command line STDIN

Tags: gnupg

Is there a way to import a gpg secret/private key from a paste of the actual key on the command line?

Importing a secret key from a file would be as straight forward as:

```
$ gpg --import PATH/FILENAME
```

But how to import a command line string?

```
$ gpg --import -----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----

keystring.......................................................
................................................................
etc.............................................................
=EnD
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

*The purpose being no key file is created and therefore no shredding is necessary (bad for SSDs)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gpg --import` without a filename should just import from STDIN. So type `gpg --import` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, paste your key and end it with a line consisting only of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (like with any program that reads from STDIN).